# Cannot get 12.04 or 14.04 to work?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

So my video card is nvidia 6150se and before I can even type in my password, it freezes. I am using 12.04 in "demo mode" right now, but when I try to start the installed version, it goes to a blank purple screen. I tried 14.04 and that would crash after I put my password in. Is my video card non-compatible with Ububntu? Is there a different distro I should use? I am really new to Linux, please help me!

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it's the video card?